# How to get the list of contextmenu items when right clicking document icon

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, msdn, shell-extensions

I tried to use this piece of code but it does not give any information.

```
        WCHAR szString[256];
        MENUITEMINFO mf;
        int pos=0;
        ZeroMemory(&mf, sizeof(mf));                     
        mf.cbSize = sizeof(mf);
        mf.fMask = MIIM_STRING;
        mf.fType = MFT_STRING;
        mf.cch = 256;
        mf.dwTypeData = szString;
          for (pos = GetMenuItemCount(hmenu); --pos >= 0; )       
            if (GetMenuItemInfo(hmenu, (UINT) pos, TRUE, &mf))   
                if (mf.dwTypeData == L"Print"){
                    bool x= false;
                    x= true;
                    return TRUE;
                }
```

GetMenuItemInfo function does not produce any results. The HMENU i was using was from `QueryContextMenu()` function, which is supposedly wrong. Any direction anyone could give?

Comment: `hmenu` should be ok if GetMenuITemCount is > 0. Check the remarks in GetMenuItemInfo official doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms647980.aspx you're supposed to query strings in 2 passes.

Comment: yes it worked.. thanks. But the issue i found is, it only retrieves the items from mid to end ignoring the top items in the list. I tried to loop from 0 also, still it starts from the mid- section.

Comment: This is another issue. It means the menu is modified after you query it.